# I want to convert vb this code

Tags: php, asp.net, vb.net

I want to convert vb this code

```
<?php
// Where the file is going to be placed
$target_path = "uploads/";

/* Add the original filename to our target path.
Result is "uploads/filename.extension" */
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']).
    " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    echo "filename: " .  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
    echo "target_path: " .$target_path;
}
?>
```

please explain your scenario more clearly.

Comment: "please explain your scenario more clearly." -- you first! Do you want to convert from php to vb? I would call that rewrite, not convert.

Comment: I want to convert asp.net this code

Comment: its php; the question is tagged vb (visual basic) what are you talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google it to find so many code examples on "how to upload files using asp.net".

Some are as follows:

- [Sample code](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/controls/file-upload-control/)
- [From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479405.aspx)

Just go through the examples & tutorials, and make changes to it to suit your needs.

Hope it helps :)